# What will be the value in float if I have a binary number as 1111111111111111 and the storage formats used by Intel processors is 32 bits?

Tags: c, memory, processor

I have to represent a binary number in floating point number.
I have a hexadecimal number as FFFF, when I am converting this hexadecimal number into Binary I am getting the corresponding binary number as 1111111111111111.
The storage formats used by my Intel processor is 32 bits means 1 bit for the sign, 8 bits for the exponent, and 23 bits for the mantissa.
I have some idea but quite confused.
Can Anyone help me out what will be the corresponding float value for this binary number??

Comment: `FFFF` is two bytes (16 bit), not 32 bit (4 bytes). Either you have `FFFFFFFF` (8x F) or you mixed up something else.

Comment: Why won't you just try this yourself?

Comment: Why don't you explain better, and more calmed.

Comment: Is this a homework problem or do you a real issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: @delnan: I have only this Hex Number as (FFFF). Yes of course Some numbers(binary bits) will be mixed to completely represent this into 32 bit storage system. That is the main problem I am facing that How and in what manner this number FFFF will be store actually in the memory??

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: No Raymond it is not a homework it a real issue that I am facing and asking for help..

Comment: @AshA In that case, I'm very curious about what your real use case is.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: My Real use case is an embedded application...

Answer (score 4):

## 32 ones

Simply try it out:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  union {
    unsigned i;
    float f;
  } u;
  u.i = 0xffffffff;
  printf("%f\n", u.f);
  return 0;
}
```

prints `-nan`. This experiment assumes that you actually wanted `0xffffffff` not `0xffff` as your question states.

Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision you find that exponent `0xFF` together with a non-zero significand is treated as NaN.

## 16 ones

If you really are after `0xFFFF` only, as your question writes, then the code will print `0.000000`, but changing the `%f` to `%g` you get `9.18341e-41`. This is because both the integer and the float use the same endianess, i.e. you are talking about the float corresponding to the bit pattern `0x0000ffff`.

There you see that you'll now have zero sign (i.e. positive), zero exponent and a non-zero significand. According to the same wikipedia article, this represents a [subnormal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_numbers). So this is really 0xffff ∙ 2<sup>−149</sup> = 65535 ∙ 2<sup>−149</sup>.

Comment: He wanted 0xffff, not 0xffffffff. It will be just the same number I guess

Comment: Nice application for unions.

Comment: @SergeyS, I assumed there was a mistake in the question in this regard, but you are right, this need not be the case, so I edited my answer to address this as well.

Comment: @MvG: Yes you are rite.I result will be NaN and the Actual Result I am getting as zero(0.00). Is it the value of NaN or anything else???

Answer (score 3):

Assuming IEEE-754 32-bit float, `0xFFFFFFFF` (so 32 ones):

The first is the sign, so it's a negative float.
Then comes the exponent, since it's the maximum value, it's a "special" exponent.

Because the significand is not zero, the result is `NaN`.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding).

If you just want 16 ones, then:

<del>Assuming the remaining bits are zero and we're using little-endian, we'll have `0xFFFF0000`.  
This is still not enough for the significand to be zero, so the result is still `NaN`. In fact, regardless of which values you pick for the last 16 bits, the result will always be `NaN`.</del>

Apparently, this is not the case as demonstrated by MvG.

Assuming the remaining bits are zero, the input is `0x0000FFFF`. The first bit is the sign, which is a zero. So we have a positive float.
Then we have 8 bits for the exponent. Since they are all zero, we'll have (depending on the fraction) either zero or a subnormal number.
Because the fraction is not all zeroes, this float is a subnormal number.
At this point, we've checked 9 bits, so there are still 7 extra zeroes.
The fraction is made of 7 zeroes, followed by 16 ones, therefore the significand is (in binary) `0.00000001111111111111111`. Multiply that by `2e-126` and you'll have your answer.
The result is, apparently, `9.18341e-41`.

Comment: My experiment (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13673089/1468366)) indicates that the correct padding would be `0x0000ffff` not `0xffff0000`.

Comment: @luiscubal: Thank You It is really helpful. Ya I got the result will be NaN. But the Actual Result I am getting as zero(0). Is it the value of NaN or anything else???

Comment: @MvG Interesting. The fact that the floats would be read in little-endian too caught me by surprise.

Comment: @luiscubal: Your answer and my actual result(0) is matching. Because If I will convert 0x0000FFFF in Binary the corresponding pattern would be 0(sign) 00000000(exponent) 00000001111111111111111(mantissa). So the corresponding float-binary representation will be 1.00000001111111111111111 x 2^-127(exponent(0) - bias(127)). And the respective float-decimal number will be 9.1834E-41 which will turns to zero(0).

Comment: @AshA It would be 1.*** for most exponents, but not for this particular one. For the exponent zero, the representation is 0.***.