# In floating point representation, what decimal value is represented as 0 100000010 010000 . . . 0

Tags: math

what decimal value is represented as 0 100000010 010000 . . . 0 ?  How can you work this out?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to know what standard the floating point is expressed in.

[IEEE 754 is just one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).  There are others, depending on how old this piece of data is, or where you're getting it from.

Just because the number is 64 bits doesn't mean that it has a unique representation in decimal.  It depends on the number of exponent bits, mantissa bits, offsets, etc.  For example, [IBM Floating Point Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture) is different.

Comment: 9 bits for an excess-8 exponent nd the remaining 54 bits for the mantissa. The notional binary point is assumed to be just left of the left most bit of the signicand. The signicand is normalised, so that its leftmost bit is always 1

Comment: I suggest editing your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

> How can you work this out?

Convert the number to hexadecimal, then assign it to a memory location and read from that location interpreting it as a float or double. In `C`, you could use an `union` to interpret the same piece of memory in different ways.

See also [What will be the value in float if I have a binary number as 1111111111111111 and the storage formats used by Intel processors is 32 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13673045/1468366) about details on how to do this.

As an alternative to experiments, you can of course read documents like the WIkipedia articles for [single](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) or [double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) precision floats, and work out the consequences for your input from that.